# How to change the meta tag title of the homepage in expressionengine?

Tags: html, expressionengine, expressionengine3

I m trying to change the tag title  of the homepage but I can't locate the homepage in the cms . I can't edit the layout page since it generates the tag title dynamically on the code below . Does anyone know how to locate the home page in the cms  ?

```
{!--choozle tag--}
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//nexus.ensighten.com/choozle/200/Bootstrap.js"></script>
{!--end choozle--}

{if layout:meta_title}
     <title>{layout:meta_title} | {site_name} </title>
     <meta name='description' content='{layout:meta_description}' />
     <meta property="og:description" content=" {layout:meta_description}" />
     <meta property="og:title" content=">{layout:meta_title}" />

{if:else}
   {exp:seo_lite use_last_segment="yes"}
{/if}


{if layout:og-image}
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="{layout:og-image}" >
{if:else}
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="{lv-og-url}/images/og-logo.png" >
{/if}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template is using layouts, so in the template calling the layout template, you have to set it as {layout:meta_title}.

Read more on layout templates here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html